# Changing color permanently in a submit button does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jinja2

I have this HTML code using jinja template:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="backup-styles.css"> -->
   <body>
         <h3>Select the devices to push to</h3> 
         {% for question in questions %}
            {% set foo = "hostname" %}
            <form method="POST" action="/questions">  
               <!-- <input type="checkbox" value="{{question[foo]}}" name="a"> -->
               <input id="{{question[foo]}}" class="btn btn-default" onclick="document.getElementById('priceform').submit()" onmousedown="change(this.id)" type="submit" value="{{question[foo]}}" name="a"> 
               
            </form>
            
            <br>
         {% endfor %}

         <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function change(id){
                  localStorage.setItem("background","#7CFC00");
                  document.cookie = '#7CFC00'
                  document.getElementById(id).style.background = localStorage.getItem("background");
           }
         </script>

         <form method="POST">
            <textarea name="textarea" style="width:250px;height:150px;"></textarea>   
            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit"> 
         </form>

         <pre> {{ content }} <pre>

   </body>
</html>
```

I have used the Javascript to change the submit button color, but I want it to stay the same color permanently after the click and only return to normal on refresh or click through some another button. I even tried using cookie and local storage as shown in the code above. Is it because of the for loop?

Comment: If you change a color it is 'permanent'. It stays that way until you change it again or page refresh. If you want it to stay AFTER page refresh. Load color from LocalStorage and set it on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure your framework isn't running a script in the background that changes or overrides your button's style?

You could try a couple of things:

1. define a new class for the button color in CSS (e.g call it `"btn-selected"`) and set that class instead of setting button.style.background
2. put the button tag inside a `{% block %} ... {% endblock %}` declaration, as that should stop jinja from overriding the button, if that's what's actually happening.